# The Tribonacci constant and the Dragon

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, fractals, transcendental-numbers, constants

Let $x = \frac{\ln T}{\ln 2} = 0.879146\dots$ where $T$ is the *[tribonacci constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciConstant.html)*, then *x* solves the transcendental equation,

$$4^x(2^x-1)=(2^x+1)$$

Let $x = \frac{\ln y}{\ln 2} = 1.523627\dots$ where $y$ is the real root of the cubic $y^3-y^2-4y-4=0$ (hence $x=1.5236\dots$ is the boundary of the *[dragon curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve)*), then *x* solves,

$$4^x(2^x-1)=4(2^x+1)$$

In general, given the *transcendental equation* with unknown $x$ and algebraic  constants $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i$,

$$ (a_1p_1^x + b_1) (a_2 p_2^x + b_2) \dots  = (c_1q_1^x + d_1) (c_2q_2^x + d_2)\dots\tag{1}$$

for the special case when $p = p_i = q_i$, then the solution to $(1)$ for $p \ne 0, 1$ is $x = \frac{\ln z}{\ln\, p}$ where $z$ is a root of the *algebraic equation*,

$$(a_1z + b_1) (a_2z + b_2) \dots  = (c_1z + d_1) (c_2z + d_2) \dots$$

***Question***: Excluding using the *[Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_Function)*, is there any other special case of the transcendental equation $(1)$ that has a *simple* closed-form solution?

Comment: If there exits $p$ such that $p_i=p^{e_i}$ and $q_i=p^{d_i}$ with $e_i,d_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, we obtain another algebraic relation setting $z=p^x$.  In fact, it suffices for $e_i,d_i$ to be rational.

Comment: @A Walker: Ah, I get what you mean. Mine was just the case $d_i = e_i = 1$.